# Subtract then divide SQL without rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Want to subtract one column from another then divide by first and show as a percentage
TRYING THIS

```
Select SUM(GoodReadCount)As 'GoodReads'
  ,'GoodRead%' = ((SUM (GoodReadCount)-SUM (NoReadCount))/SUM (GoodReadCount))
  ,SUM(NoReadCount)AS 'NoReads'
  ,SUM(NoInformationCount)AS'NoInfo'
  ,SUM(LabelConflictCount)AS'Label'
  ,SUM(TrackingErrorRecircCount)AS'TrackError'
  ,SUM(ConfirmCount)as'confirmed'
  ,SUM(RecircCount)as 'recirc'
FROM [DB].[DB].[dbo].[SorterStats]
WHERE RecordedPeriod Between '6/19/2017 01:00:00AM' and '6/23/2017 23:59:00PM'
```

Getting this result

```
GoodReads   GoodRead%   NoReads NoInfo  Label   TrackError  confirmed   recirc
21202              0    317     2       5170    8565        13007       12881
```

Would like to see this result

```
GoodReads   GoodRead%   NoReads NoInfo  Label   TrackError  confirmed   recirc
21202       98.5%       317     2       5170    8565          13007     12881
```

DATA TYPES ARE INT

Comment: So what is the problem with the SQL you've posted? You haven't explained why it's not what you wanted. You've also not told us what data type your columns are; how are they declared?

Comment: May be you should read something about [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql).

Comment: What are you getting and what are you expecting to get?

Comment: apologies, I explained incorrectly. I have updated the question

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
 cast((SUM (GoodReadCount)-SUM (NoReadCount)) as decimal(8,2))*100/ cast(SUM (GoodReadCount)as decimal(4,2))
```

or

```
cast(cast((SUM (GoodReadCount)-SUM (NoReadCount))*100.00/SUM (GoodReadCount) as decimal(4,1)) as varchar(10)) + '%'
```

Would do the trick. If you divide it and then later cast it there is no use because the divided number is an integer and when you cast it, you are simply adding two zeros after the decimal point

Comment: cool, your second script works, I am getting 0.9850485803226 as result....How can we have this show as just 98.5%

Comment: 1st option I get error ,,,,,,,Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. 2nd option now shows         98.5048580322611

Comment: the overflow error is because the (4,2) is too small for 21200.00.  Change them to (8,2).

Comment: now im showing error.....Incorrect syntax near '|'........... When I remove the ||"%" it shows 98.50.......looking better.....I appreciate your guys' help, would really like to see the %

Comment: @RaunakThomas, I used your second option......I changed || "%" to + '%'..................this works perfect, if you want to update option 2, then ill check as answer,,,,,,,,i really appreciate your help, and everyone elses for trying to help

Answer (score 4):

Put the subtraction in parens so it is executed before the division.

```
(A-B)/C
```

Also cast/convert the datatypes to DECIMAL(4,2) to avoid the result being automatically rounded.

Comment: Tried this ,'GoodRead%'= (cast(SUM (GoodReadCount)-SUM (NoReadCount))/SUM (GoodReadCount)as decimal(4,2))

Comment: Put a separate CAST on both sides of the division operator.  It won't work to just use one CAST for the whole operation.

Comment: you're going to want a little more generously sized decimal to hold 21200.00.   Try a (8,2) -- that will accommodate your inputs.  Division does wonky stuff with the length and precision of the output, so you won't end up with an(8,2) on the other side.  I'd have to look it up to remember how that works tho.  For simplicity, maybe just do them all as floats.